# Are our variables dynamic?

Tags: scope, raku

This code will print out 'Duo' even though $var is not a dynamic variable with a `*` twigil:

```
our $var="Duo";
sub sub1() {
    say $*var;
}

sub1();
#output is 'Duo'
```

Adding  a `unit package ABC;` at the start gives a compile time error "Dynamic variable $*var not found":

```
unit package ABC;

our $var="Duo";
sub sub1() {
    say $*var;
}

sub1();
# compile time error
```

Adding  a * twigil in this case makes the variable accessible.

Why the difference?

**Edit 1:**

Using `my` instead of `our` is a compile time error with or without a package, even though this would mean the same lexical scope in my understanding.

Are variables which are intended to be used dynamically, to be declared explicitly as such (like all the examples I can find). If so how does `our` allow the above to work? I'm confused.

**Edit 2:**

I think the following demonstrates why I'm confused:

```
our $var="non dynamic";   #1
{say $*var;}

our $*var="dynamic";      #2
{say $*var;}


#With #2 commented output is
#non dynamic
#non dynamic
#
#With #2 in place output becomes
#(Any)
#dynamic
```

In the first case (#2 commented) I'm accessing a non dynamic variable dynamically (twice).

In the second case the `our $var` variable is getting clobbered when the `our $*var` is declared and accessing same dynamic variable is resolving to two seperate variables.

Comment: The FQN name would be `$*ABC::var`, I guess.

Comment: @jjmerelo But dynamic variables cannot have package-like names, so `$*ABC::var` would be an illegal name

Comment: So if dynamic variables are not resolvable through a package name, is there any point to being able to declare them with `our` ? Am I missing the use case?

Comment: @drclaw  *"is there any point to being able to declare them with `our`"* Not as far as I can see.. To me it seems like `our $*var` is equivalent to `my $*var`.

Comment: *"Using `my` instead of `our` is a compile time error"* Yes, if you substitute `my $var = ...` for `our $var = ...` there will not be reserved an alias in the (here: GLOBAL) symbol table at *compile time*, so when `say $*var`  is executed at *run time* there is no symbol `$GLOBAL::var` and hence `$*var` cannot be found. The run time error is: `Dynamic variable $*var not found`

Comment: *"In the second case the `our $var` variable is getting clobbered.."* Actually `$var` is not clobbered, if  you add a `say $var` after #1, it still prints "non dynamic"

Comment: @HåkonHægland To clarify, it is clobbered in the sense of referring to it with `$*var` no longer working like the first case. Using it lexically with `$var` works as you've demonstrated.

Comment: @drclaw *"referring to it with `$*var` no longer working like the first case"* Yes as I understand it: when you print #1 `$*var` has been declared at compile time (#2) but it has not been given a value at run time (will happen at #2 at run time) so for #1 it just prints as an undefined value `(Any)`

Comment: More digging around:  the paragraph before the line `augment package GLOBAL { our %ENV; }` in S02-bits.pod gives some insight into our/dynamic variables stripping twigil names. Makes slightly more sense now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like dynamic variables are looked up in the [`GLOBAL` name space](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Globals). Thus the following works:

```
unit package ABC;

$GLOBAL::var="Duo";
sub sub1() {
    say $*var;
}
sub1();
#output is 'Duo'
```

The reason your first example works is that (according to the [documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Globals)):

> The user's program starts in the `GLOBAL` package, so "our" declarations
>   in the mainline code go into that package by default.

Comment: `sub1()` is in the same package ABC and is still accessible. Would not `our $var` also be directly accessible from within the same package without explicit namespace? I thought `our` was like `my` but adds an alias in the symbol table somehow.

Comment: *"Would not our `$var` also be directly accessible from within the same package without explicit namespace?"* Yes it is, but it is not the same variable as the dynamic variable `our $*var`. The one without the star, `our $var`, makes a lexical variable and also make `$ABC::var` accessible from other packages by using the fully qulified name. On the other hand `our $*var` declares a dynamic variable (not lexical); this variable will not be accessible from other packages using a fully qualified name.

Comment: It could of course happen that `$*var` could be accessible from other packages if that package's code was called from the scope  that defined the variable in package `ABC`, but in this case it would not be accessible using a fully qualified name, but rather as the simple `$*var`.

Comment: I think I understand your example. However in my original code/question, I declared  `our $var` (with no *) and then use it as a dynamic variable like  `say $*var;` and I get the expected result. This is the bit I'm not following: how and why is our dynamic? (or not, and I'm just missing the point!)

Comment: *"and I get the expected result"* Yes that was because the code was running in the `GLOBAL` package and then `our $var` was put into the `GLOBAL` namespace (as I mentioned in my answer). My guess is that in the `GLOBAL` scope somehow `our $*var` is the same as `our $var`. So later when you do `say $*var` it would look up dynamic variables in the callers scopes until it comes back to the top most scope which is the `GLOBAL` scope. It then finds `$*var` here..

Answer (score 6):

Dynamic variable lookup conceptually happens in all **dynamic** scopes.  Dynamic scopes are first `PROCESS::`, then `GLOBAL::` and then whatever dynamic scopes that the program has.

So when you look up a dynamic variable, it will first look in all dynamic scopes from the current down.  When it doesn't find it there, it will then look in `GLOBAL::`, and if not found, in `PROCESS::`.

For example, if you want to print something on STDOUT, it will look up the `$*OUT` dynamic variable.  If you did not define one somewhere in your dynamic scopes, it will use the one from `PROCESS::`:

```
dd PROCESS::<$OUT>;
# IO::Handle element = IO::Handle.new(path => IO::Special.new("<STDOUT>")...)
```

Comment: I think part of my confusion comes from the twigil being  part of the variable name. So `our $*var` and `our $var` would be different variables in my thinking. Why look for `$var` when asked to find `$*var`

Comment: I think the reasoning was that the `*` twigil indicates a way to look up, rather than a type.  Personally, I consider this a wart, similar to `class A { has $a = 42; method b() { $!a } }; dd A.new.b; # 42`, where you can specify a private attribute **without** the `!` sigil.